# Console error: image not found

Tags: angularjs, twig

Some context:
I'm using a `.twig` file to display some `.png` images, like this

`<img class="output-icons" src="{{ asset('path/to/images/output_icon_' ~ '{{ output.slug }}' ~ '.png') }}">`

The images are all named `output_icon_(output.slug).png`; `output.slug` has 11 different slugs, same number of pictures I have. here's a picture name example: `output_icon_balance.png`.

So far so good, it all works as it should, but even tho all 11 pictures are being displayed, the console is showing this 
`GET URL/path/output_icon_%7B%7B%20output.slug%20%7D%7D.png?v2212 404 not found`

Comment: Try using ng-src={{}}

Comment: @Vivz That did the trick, thank you! Care to explain the difference ?

Comment: I have written the explanation in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-src` to render images defined on your scope. The reason is that browser will read it as {{variable}} assigned to your src tag instead of rendering it first and then assigning. So, ng-src will make sure that your variable is first rendered and then assigned to your tag.

**For more Info**:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc